# align table footer right

Tags: html, css

I have a table which contains data and I want the first footer item to be aligned left and the remaining ones to be aligned right.

Here is expected results:

[image]

```css
table {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<table class="price-list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Quantidade</th>
      <th>Preço</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>text1</td>
      <td>text2</td>
      <td>text3</td>
      <td>text4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot class="footer">
    <tr align="left">
      <td id="cart_voucher" class=" cart_voucher">
        <form action="http://localhost:8080/index.php?controller=order-opc" method="post" id="voucher">
          <div class="form-group form-group-placeholder">
            <input type="text" class="discount_name form-control" id="discount_name" name="discount_name" placeholder="Kod rabatowy" value="">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right discount_icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <input type="hidden" name="submitDiscount">
          </div>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end VOUCHER -->
    <!-- Total products -->
    <tr align="right">
      <td>Total products </td>
      <td id="total_product">500,00 zł</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="right">
      <td Total shipping (tax incl.):>
      </td>
      <td id="total_shipping" class="price-opc">12,00 zł</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="right">
      <td>Total (tax excl.):</td>
      <td id="total_price_without_tax" class="price-opc">418,50 zł</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end Total tax excl. -->
    <!-- Total tax -->
    <tr align="right">
      <td>Total tax:</td>
      <td>93,50 zł</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end Total tax -->
    <tr align="right">
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>
        <span>512,00 zł</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

I used inline `align="left"` for first footer element and `align="right"`for the remaining ones. I get the following:

[image]

**UPDATE more explanation**
 In a footer we have form input and other data , form input should be left and the remaining footer element should be right as image describe below
[image]

I tried using `flex-box` for each `tr` but nothing worked. Can someone please help me? I just want the first element in the footer to align left and the rest to align right. Thanks, any help or suggestions will be helpful. Ignore `thead` and `tbody`, just consider `tfoot`.

Comment: Which element are you trying to align right?

Comment: @WebGuy  all footer elements with currencies except  input form should be left

Comment: @WebGuy did you try?

Comment: Working on it....

Comment: Does it have to be responsive?

Comment: Yes, mobile first aproach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply `float` attribute for which accept `right` or `left` velues

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Left Child</div>
  <div class="right">Right Child</div>
</div>
```

This is how the attribute is work

Comment: okay, Let me try , here is jsfiddle u can try urself if it works https://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/4ua9zk0n/36/

Comment: this does not work bro here is the jsfiddle check it urself  your solution https://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/4ua9zk0n/45/

Comment: I could not  understand exactly what is your goal can you explain more, I will code it for you

Comment: In a table u have footer elements which contains several data  and a form input, so I want the form input to be left and the remaing table footer elements to the right

Comment: I have added image for explanantion

Comment: close to what I want , Thanks alot , is it possible to make data with red color to float them to end of right side, right now there is remaining space right side?

Comment: @user9964622 Just set align and colspan attribute to the right cell: `<td class="right" align="right" colspan="3">`. See: https://jsfiddle.net/3sygp79k/1/